# Contact form error 404

Tags: email, forms, contact-us

I created a contact form with cms -> page , some html code and adding the this at the end :

```
{{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' form_action='/contacts/index/post' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}
```

The contact form site will open normally but when im actually sending the message I got a 404 error "The requested URL was not found on the server" How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Check contacts form module is enable. In admin > system > configuration > advanced

Comment: contacts form is enable

Comment: Check your form action url and you set it manually

Comment: Yeah this works but somehow the layout for my contact form page changed. What is happening now?

Comment: Ok I see now I changed the layout in general - how can I reset my old standards?

Comment: ok got it ty! .